# perl negative lookahead for not matching a word

Tags: regex, perl

I found a regex not to match a word from this question [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/2610955) .

`u(?!i)` will match a word with u not followed by i. The answer says that it checks if each character is not followed by hede. So shouldn't the regex be `/^(.(?!hede))*$/`. It works for words containing hede but not starting with it. Why do they use `/^((?!hede).)*$/` . Whats the difference between the position of the dot. I used `re=debug` but couldn't still get the meaning

Comment: Re "shouldn't the regex be `/^(.(?!hede))*$/`? That will match `hede` since no character is followed by `hede`. You need to start checking at position 0, not position 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!hede)` means **look ahead** to see if there is not: `hede`. So it make sense if there is any other character followed by `hede` hence `.` after `(?!hede)` is the valid regex.

Regex explanation of `^((?!hede).)*$`

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times):
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
      hede                     'hede'
    )                        end of look-ahead
    .                        any character except \n
  )*                       end of \1
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

---

Use `(?<!` for **look behind**

Pattern explanation of `^(.(?<!hede))*$`

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times):
    .                        any character except \n
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
      hede                     'hede'
    )                        end of look-behind
  )*                       end of \1
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

---

It's better explained under [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not

Comment: Thanks so how can I use a negative lookbehind to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks again. Was just typing it.

Comment: In case of negative lookbehind is the pattern asserted before consuming the first character with the dot?

Comment: Only `hede` that is used inside `(?!` and `(?<!` will not be consumed in both the cases.

Comment: So a character is consumed only when the assertion is true right? @Braj

Comment: Can you provide me some input strings so that I can explain you?

Comment: hede, ashede, hedeas, ashedeas are some input strings

Comment: Have a look at the [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zX6sT9/1) where `ashede` and `ashedeas` are matches. Look at the correct regex pattern as well.

Comment: Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zX6sT9/2) for Look-behind where `hedeas` and `ashedeas` are matches

Answer (score 1):

```
`^((?!hede).)*$` means check for condtion ,then consume.
```

Due to anchors it will not accept any string containing `hede`.

See demo:

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/17

```
`^(.(?!hede))*$` means consume,then check for condition.
```

(that is why words starting from `hede` were passing because first character was `h` and it had no `hede` ahead of it. So it was a pass).

Comment: @Wordzilla remove anchors to get a better understanding of what's happending